# Visual studio code disappear breakpoint with debugging lauching.json

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
        We need information, I try debugging process to Visual Studio Code and I use breakpoint after sample debugging breakpoint disappear:
        
  {
   // Use IntelliSense to find out which attributes exist for C# debugging
   // Use hover for the description of the existing attributes
   // For further information visit https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/master/debugger-launchjson.md
   "version": "0.2.0",
   "configurations": [
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            // If you have changed target frameworks, make sure to update the program path.
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.2/DatingApp.API.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            // Enable launching a web browser when ASP.NET Core starts. For more information: https://aka.ms/VSCode-CS-LaunchJson-WebBrowser
            "serverReadyAction": {
                "action": "openExternally",
                "pattern": "\\bNow listening on:\\s+(https?://\\S+)"
            },
            "env": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
            },
            "sourceFileMap": {
                "/Views": "${workspaceFolder}/Views"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Attach",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach",
            "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I start debugging, the breakpoint disappears completely and I cannot verify the steps in my application.
I will add that I send data from Postman as a record to the sqlite database, the data goes to the application but I cannot see it step by step after debugging.

What could be causing the problem?

Answer (score 1):

It might sound dumb, but did you try renaming the file?

I had a similar issue with Node.js, tried reinstalling vscode, disabling the debugger, and could not get to work, but when i changed the file name, it worked...

Comment: Worked for me too, but I did have a space in the filename,  I wonder if that was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

in ***package.json*** file change or add scripts block to:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "export NODE_ENV=test || SET NODE_ENV=test && nodemon --exec npm start",
    "golive": "export NODE_ENV=go || SET NODE_ENV=go && nodemon --exec npm start"
},
```